# Prove that for every positive rational number $r$ where $r^2<2$, there must be another rational number $r+h$, such that $(r+h)^2<2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification

**Question**

Prove that for every positive rational number $r$ satisfying the condition $r^2<2$ one can always find a larger rational number $r+h$ ($h>0$) for which $(r+h)^2<2$.

**The book's solution**

We may assume $h<1$.

Then $h^2<h$ and $(r+h)^2<r^2+2rh+h$.

That is why it is sufficient to put $r^2+2rh+h = 2$, i.e., $h = \frac{2-r^2}{2r+1}$.

**Note:** As Ben in the comment section pointed out, this solution is wrong .

For example, when $r=\frac{1}{10}$, the value of h comes out to be $\frac{199}{120}$ and thus contradicts the assumption $h<1$.

**My attempt**

We have been given the following information:-
$$r \in Q$$
$$r > 0$$
$$r^2<2$$

Let us first use the third piece of information to find the interval in which $r$ lies:-

$$r^2<2$$
$$r^2-2>0$$
$$(r-\sqrt2)(r+\sqrt2)<0$$

[image]

We can see that the value of the product is negative only in the interval between $-\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt2$.

But also $r$ is positive, therefore we get 
$$r \in (0,\sqrt2)$$

Now we have to prove that for every $r$, there exists a larger rational number $r+h$ which is bound by the following conditions:-
$$(r+h)\in Q$$
$$(r+h) > 0$$
$$(r+h)^2 < 2$$

Again we can figure out the following:-
$$ (r+h) \in (0,\sqrt2)$$

So for every positive rational number $r$ which satisfies the condition $r^2<2$, we can always find a larger number $r+h$ in the interval $(0,\sqrt2)$ that satisfies the condition $(r+h)^2<2$. This is because there are an infinite number of positive rational numbers in the interval $(0,\sqrt2)$, just like there are an infinite number of natural numbers.

Do you think this solution is right?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2697010/how-to-prove-that-x-in-mathbbq-such-that-s2-x2-5/2697013#2697013 for a very similar problem.

Comment: The book's solution is NOT correct.  Consider r = 1/10.  Then h = 199/120 which is a contradiction, because it was assumed that h < 1.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's poorly worded (or transcribed) indeed, but the book presumably assumes that $r+1 \gt \sqrt{2}$ otherwise $h=1$ will work.

Comment: @Abhishek: If you are willing to go with negative h then simply choose $$h = -2r$$.  Your current solution is incorrect because you haven't defined the range of allowed h for each value of r.

Comment: @dxiv: Certainly it's possible to fix, for example simply adding 1 to the denominator of the expression should do it.  But a proof that is "easy to fix" is still an invalid proof.

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't think I need to define the range of $h$ for each value $r$ if I can find the maximum and minimum value it can go very near (though not equal to). If I have extremes that $h$ can go very, the rest of the values are irrelevant to me as long as there are rational.

Comment: @AbhishekMhatre `My solution` All that proves is that *if* $h$ exists then it must be within a certain interval. But what you *needed* to prove is that such an $h$ does in fact exist.

Comment: "We know that $(r+h)^2<2$".  Uh, of course you don't know that!  That is what you are trying to prove.  $−\sqrt 2<r<\sqrt 2$.  What is $\sqrt 2$?  That is a symbol that doesn't have any meaning.  We don't know that there is any real number so that $x^2 = 2$ and we certainly have no idea what size it is.  To assume it even exist and is measurable is to assume precisely what you are trying to prove.  So your prove is complete circular.

Comment: @dxiv I'm not a philosopher but if h exists in a certain interval, surely that also proves that h does in fact exist.

Comment: @fleablood We have to find the value of $h$ such that a rational number r satisfies the condition $r^2<2$ and that $(r+h)^2<2$. Those two inequalities are conditions. Hence we must assume they are true. The rest of over post seems to be incomprehensible, at least to me.

Comment: @AbhishekMhatre `We know that (r+h)^2 < 2` It doesn't take a philosopher to see that you start by ***assuming*** that such an $h$ exists. You do ***not*** know that, and that's precisely what you have to prove.

Comment: You have ignored the condition that $r+h$ is supposed to be larger than $r$.

Comment: @dxiv We are not proving whether h exists or not. How in the world would we even prove that. What we are proving is that h is a rational number(as the question says it is) that follows the given conditions.

Comment: @AbhishekMhatre `We are not proving whether h exists or not` Then what on earth do you think you are proving? Read again the book's solution - what it does is precisely proving that such an $h$ exists, and in the end it gives an explicit expression for $h$. You can do it in different ways if you wish to, but you still have to do the same thing - prove that such an $h$ exists.

Comment: @dxiv We are not proving whether h as a number exists. We can easily show that h is not only a number, but a rational number since we have been given that r is a rational number, r+h is a rational number, h has to be a rational number. We are simply proving that h is a rational number(which I just did) that follows the given conditions

Comment: @AbhishekMhatre Sorry, but you completely misunderstand what the problem is asking for. Bye now.

Comment: @dxiv Well at least give a like to bring it to the attention of someone who does understand it and can explain it to me.

Comment: The word "larger" is used in the question.

Comment: Dxiv and I did a good job understanding and explaining.

Comment: "Well at least give a like to bring it to the attention of someone who does understand it and can explain it to me."  Are you out of your mind?  Why on earth would we like a question of someone who butchered the meaning and then argued with people who made clear and simple critique and insisted they must be wrong?  And who despite having the issue explained by three different people then asks for someone smarter.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen You are right, I forgot to write the word "larger" in the question bar and mistook that h can be negative. I have made the appropriate changes. I hope you take a second look.

Comment: @fleablood given the fact that you think my answer is wrong and you don't have an answer, I think it makes sense that someone else more capable than either of us tries to answer the question and that won't happen if you keep disliking the question.

Comment: @fleablood In all fairness, the OP just wants the right answer. And you haven't attempted the question. Why dislike someone's question just because you don't like them,

Comment: "the OP just wants the right answer" The OP *has* a correct answer.  The book answer is correct (albeit badly written). The question was a proof validation.  The proof is wrong because 1) it assumes what it wants to prove and 2) It presumes that $\sqrt{2}$ exists and is a known value.  The entire point of this exercise is to lay the groundwork to prove that a real number, $\sqrt{2}$, is meaningful and well defined.

Comment: @fleablood Isn't there a contradiction in the book's answer.

Comment: No, there is not.  The book assumed that $r \ge 1$ but didn't state it.  That is not a contradiction.  It's an omission.  And a minor one.   The book merely assumed it was obvious that if $r \ge 1$ then it's trivial that $h = 1 - r$ is such that $(r +h)^2 = 1^2 < 2$ exists.  So we can assume the result is trivial and obvious if $r < 1$ and we only have to show it for $r \ge 1$.

Comment: Arrgh!...."The book merely assumed it was obvious that if $r < 1$ then it's trivial that..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not assume that there exists a real number that you refer to as $\sqrt 2$.  Namely you have no reason to presume that there exists a real number, $x$ so that $x^2 = 2$.  That is precisely what this proof is supposed to establish.

If we know what irrational real numbers are, and if we know that $\sqrt 2$ actually exists, then this exercise simply follows by definitions.  To be a real number, by definition, $\sqrt{2}$ is a least upper bound of a sequence of rational numbers all less than $\sqrt{2}$.  So if any rational number, $r < \sqrt{2} = $ least upper bound of rational numbers less than $\sqrt{2}$ then there must be, by definition of least upper bound, a rational number $q$ (and $h= q-r$) so that $r < q=r+h \le \sqrt 2$.  And as there is no rational number $q$ so that $q^2 = 2$ we know that $r < q=r+h < \sqrt 2$.

There was nothing to prove.  It all followed by definition.

This exercise usually comes before the definition of the real numbers as an exercise to introduce the idea of a least upper bound.  For any rational $r$ so that $r^2 < 2$, we must show that we can "get closer" to the idea of the square root of $2$ by finding a larger rational $q$ so that $r < q$ and $q^2 < 2$.

The book answer makes a few unstated assumptions (well, actually only one very obvious assumption) but it is correct (although it doesn't explicitly spell it out so it is hard to see).  But here it is with more and correct details.

Preliminary:  For any $0 < p < q$ it is true that $0< p^2 < q^2$.  This is because $p< q$ and $p > 0$ so $p*p < q*p$.  And $q > 0$ and $p < q$ we know that $p*q < q*q$ and so $p^2 < p*q < q^2$.

We can assume $r \ge 1$ because $1^2 = 1 < 2$. so if $r < 1$ we are done by letting $r+h = 1$.  But we need to prove this is true for *ALL* rational $r$ where $r^2 < 2$.

So if $r \ge 1$ and ***IF*** such an $h$ exist we can assume $h < 1$.  Because if $h \ge 1$ then $(r + h)^2 = r^2 + 2rh + h^2 \ge 1 + 2*1*1 + 1^2 = 4 > 2$.

Now we can do what your book does.  .... Let's see; what *does* your book do?....

Let $h = \frac {2 - r^2}{2r + 1}$.  We must prove that 1) $h> 0$ (and therefore $r < r+h$) 2) that $h$ is rational,  and 3)that $(r+h)^2 < 2$.

1)Well $r^2 < 2$ so $2 -r^2 > 0$ and if we assume $r > 0$ we know $2r + 1 > 0$, so we have $h > 0$.

2) As $r$ is rational, so is $r^2, 2 -r^2, 2r+1$ and therefore $h =\frac {2-r^2}{2r+1}$ is rational.

And 3) is the real meat:

And as $r^2 \ge 1$ then $2-r^2 < 1$ and as $2r + 1 > 1$ we know that $h < 1$ and so $h^2 < 1$.

So

And $(r + h)^2 = r^2 + 2rh + h^2$

$ < r^2 + 2rh + h$

$ = r^2 + h(2r + 1) $

$ = r^2 + \frac {2-r^2}{2r+1}(2r+1)$

$= r^2 + 2 - r^2 = 2$.

And that completes the proof.

If $r < 1 $ then $h = 1 -r$ and $r+h = 1$ is one such rational rational number we want. (There are of course others.)

And if $r \ge 1$ and $r^2 < 2$ then $h =\frac {2-r^2}{2r+1}$ is one positive rational $h$ that we want so that $(r + h)^2 < 2$.

....

Now from there we know that we can create an infinite string of rational numbers  $r < r+h =r_1 < r_q + h_1 = r_2 < r_3 < r_4 < ......... $ all so that $r^2  < r_1^2 < r_2^2 < r_3^2 < r_4^2 < ...... < 2$.

And once we define that the real numbers have the least upper bound property, we will know that some *ir*rational real number, $x$,  is the least upper bound of $r_i$.  And we will be able to prove that $x^2 = ($ least upper bound $r_i)^2 = 2$.  Thus *THEN* we will have proven that $\sqrt 2$ exists.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to create this detailed answer after the difficult exchange of comments. You might want to note explicitly that when you "Let $h = ...$" the $h$ you get is rational.

Comment: "You might want to note explicitly that when you "Let h=..." the h you get is rational"  You know, you are right.

Comment: That was a great explanation. Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: I love your detailed answer. However, I still have a nit to pick. Near the end, where you explain how the proven claim can be applied to show that $\sqrt{2}$ exists, you don't make it clear that an increasing sequence of rationals whose squares are less than $2$ does not necessarily converge to $\sqrt{2}$ unless it satisfies an additional condition.

Comment: @TaneliHuuskonen  That last bit was an outline of where we will go.  We can't actually prove $(\sup r_i)^2 = 2$ yet.  That's why I said "will".

Comment: Yes, of course. I was just suggesting it would be didactically better, IMHO, to state explicitly that $(\sup r_i)^2=2$ does not follow from what you wrote in your next-to-last paragraph ("Now from there we know..."). Otherwise, the reader may think the claim follows from the stated assumptions but the proof is excessively long.